# How to re-establish connection after communication link failure with pyodbc?

Tags: python-2.7, pyodbc

Every once in a while(maybe every few hours) my program catches an error

```
'08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Communication link failure
```

I just want to be able to catch this error and reconnect. How would i do a listener ?

This is my code...

```
#!C:/Python/python.exe -u

import pyodbc, requests, re, time, random, sys,pickle,smtplib,os
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process, Queue, current_process
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService


auth = requests.auth.HTTPProxyAuth('user', 'pwd')
proxies = {'http': 'proxies'}
user_agent = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'}
blob_service = BlobService(account_name='user', account_key='pwd')

update = ("""UPDATE DocumentList
            SET Downloaded=?, DownLoadedAs=?,DownLoadedWhen=?,DownLoadedSizeKB=?
            WHERE DocNumberSequence=?""")


def Downloader(linkQueue,fileQueue,uniqueIDQueue):

    for url in iter(linkQueue.get, 'STOP'):
        name = current_process().name
        link = url
        fileName = fileQueue.get();
        uniqueID=uniqueIDQueue.get();
        cnxn2 = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=.windows.net;DATABASE=db;UID=userPWD=pwd', autocommit=True);
        cursor2 = cnxn2.cursor()

        #if 'LAS' or '.db' in str(fileName):
            #continue

        print 'BEFORE REQUEST'

        try:
            r = requests.get(link, proxies=proxies,headers=user_agent,auth=auth,allow_redirects=False)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:    # This is the correct syntax
            print e

        content = {}; content = r.headers          

        if 'location' in content:
            link = content['location'];
            if 'content-type' in content:
                extType= content['content-type'];
                ext = re.search(r'/(\w+)',extType).group(1);
            if 'content-length' in content:
                size = float(content['content-length'])*.001
            if ext=='pdf':
                with open(fileName+'.'+ext, "wb") as datum:
                    datum.write(r.content)
                datum.close()
            elif ext=='html':
                print 'YOU ARE GETTING REDIRECT PAGE!!!!!'
                break
            elif ext=='vnd':
                ext = 'xlsx'
                with open(fileName+'.'+ext, "wb") as datum:
                    datum.write(r.content)
                datum.close()
            elif ext=='msword':
                ext = 'doc'
                with open(fileName+'.'+ext, "wb") as datum:
                    datum.write(r.content)
                datum.close()
            else:
                with open(fileName+'.'+ext, "wb") as datum:
                    datum.write(r.content)
                datum.close()

        else:
            if 'content-type' in content:
                extType= content['content-type'];
                ext = re.search(r'/(\w+)',extType).group(1);
            if 'content-length' in content:
                size = float(content['content-length'])*.001
            if ext=='pdf':
                with open(fileName+'.'+ext, "wb") as datum:
                    datum.write(r.content)
                datum.close()
            elif ext=='html':     
                server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
                server.starttls()
                server.login("user", "pwd")
                msg = "Get back to headquaters!"
                server.sendmail("email", "email", msg)
                server.quit()
                print 'YOU ARE GETTING REDIRECT PAGE!!!!!'
                continue
            elif ext=='vnd':
                ext = 'xlsx'
                with open(fileName+'.'+ext, "wb") as datum:
                    datum.write(r.content)
                datum.close()
            elif ext=='msword':
                ext = 'doc'
                with open(fileName+'.'+ext, "wb") as datum:
                    datum.write(r.content)
                datum.close()
            else:
                with open(fileName+'.'+ext, "wb") as datum:
                    datum.write(r.content)
                datum.close()   
        print 'here'
        dt = datetime.now()
        meta=[];meta1=[];meta1=[fileName,ext,link,dt,size]
        meta.append(meta1)
        #num = random.uniform(0,) 
        #time.sleep(num)
        while True:
            try:
                blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path(
                'container',
                fileName+'.'+ext,
                fileName+'.'+ext
                )
                break
            except:
                print sys.exc_info()[1]

        while True:
            try:
                updated = cursor2.execute(update,'Yes', fileName+'.'+ext, dt, size,uniqueID )
                break
            except:
                print sys.exc_info()[1]
        cnxn2.close()


        print fileName+'.'+ext
        print 'done'+(current_process().name)
        output = open(fileName+'.pkl', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(meta, output)
        output.close()
        try:
            os.remove(fileName+'.'+ext)
        except OSError:
            pass



if __name__ == '__main__':

    numFiles = int(sys.argv[2])
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=windows.net;DATABASE=;UID=;PWD=', autocommit=True);
    cursor1 = cnxn.cursor()

    cursor1.execute("""SELECT DocumentLink,DownLoadedAs,API,DocNumberSequence,StateAbbr
                      FROM  DocumentList
                      WHERE StateAbbr='CA' AND DocNumberSequence>'1253750'""")

    rows = cursor1.fetchmany(numFiles)
    linkQueue=Queue();fileQueue=Queue();uniqueIDQueue=Queue();processes =[];

    for row in rows:
            url = str(row.DocumentLink)
            linkQueue.put(url)
            uniqueID = str(row.DocNumberSequence)
            uniqueIDQueue.put(uniqueID)
            #tracking = str(row.API)
            #docType = str(row.DocumentClass)
            abbr = str(row.StateAbbr)
            fileName = row.DownLoadedAs
            fileName = fileName.split('.')[0]
            fileName = abbr+'_'+fileName+'_'+uniqueID; fileName=fileName.replace(' ','');
            fileQueue.put(fileName)

    cnxn.close()
    print "BEFORE WORKERS"
    workers = int(sys.argv[1]);
    for x in xrange(workers):
            p = Process(target=Downloader, args=(linkQueue, fileQueue, uniqueIDQueue))
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)
            linkQueue.put('STOP')
            fileQueue.put('STOP')

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

I think the error is caught already because it keeps going but i wont reconnect until I break out of that process. I have never handled an error like this before. Do i have to put the whole block of code into the try connect or can i add a listener??

Comment: What line of the code is causing the error to trigger? Probably one of the .execute() methods, but which one?

Comment: I do not get an error that actually points to a line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the error is being printed by `sys.exc_info()[0]' here:

```
    while True:
        try:
            updated = cursor2.execute(update,'Yes', fileName+'.'+ext, dt, size,uniqueID )
            break
        except:
            print sys.exc_info()[1]
```

That's a bit a guess work, but it is your only `.execute()` that is wrapped in a try / except block. To verify, you can remove the try / except and just do the `.execute()` statement you already have.

If that's the case, you can put the try / except back into place, and in `except`, try reconnecting? It is a work around, but build in a bit of a failsafe (one level) against network blips between the machine you're on and the database server. Good luck!